# How to clear cache ,History in PhantomJS browser

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have multiple test cases in that some of them are having login into website to test the functionality and some other are not required to login to test the functionality.

Issue is when one test case is login to site to test the functionality and it is storing the login session due to that my next test case which doesn't require login is getting failed.

So I would like to know how to clear cache , History in phantomjs browser

Comment: What test framework do you use? JUnit of TestNG or some similar one?

Comment: My environment is selenium with Java TestNG and Maven

Comment: So you should have BeforeTest and AfterTest that would instantiate new driver and then close it respectively. This should clear the caches.

Comment: Yes I am doing the same but still issue is raising. Especially in PhantomJS browser in remaining browsers I am not having this issue

Comment: Try this one http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/clear-cookies.html

Answer (score 1):

Update to PhantomJS 2.0 and Run using JavascriptExecutor class in selenium: `(JavascriptExecutor) driver.executeScript("
var page = this;
page.clearMemoryCache();
page.close();");`

As mentioned [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390974/phantomjs-keeping-cache)

Comment: I tried above code but getting error "errorMessage":"Can't find variable: page"

Comment: Updated answer with full code.

Comment: Still getting error "errorMessage":"undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'page.clearMemoryCache()')